# Numerical Analysis - Algorithms

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms

We have the following nested summation:

$$\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}\,a_i b_j$$

The question asks how many multiplications and additions are required to determine this sum.

I really don't know how I should approach this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with n=3 what the terms will look like?

Comment: The number of terms is $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i 1 = \sum_{i=1}^n i = \cdots$

Comment: This form uses fewer multiplications: $\sum^n_{i=1} (a_i \sum^i_{j=1}b_j)$. It also suggests how to use fewer additions.

Answer (score 1):

$n=1$

$s = a_1\,b_1$

---

$n=2$

$s = a_1\,b_1 + a_2\,b_1 + a_2\,b_2$

---

$n=3$

$s = a_1\,b_1 + a_2\,b_1 + a_2\,b_2 + a_3\,b_1 + a_3\,b_2 + a_3\,b_3$

---

In this form, the number of multiplications is:

$m = 1+2+3+...+n = \frac{n\,(n+1)}{2}$

And the number of additions is:

$a = m-1 = \frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{2}$

---

However, we may group some terms as:

$s = a_1\,b_1 + a_2\,(b_1+b_2) + a_3\,(b_1+b_2+b_3) + ... + a_n\,(b_1+...+b_n)$

Now, the number of multiplications is:

$\boxed{m = n}$

And the number of additions is still the same:

$a = \frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{2}$

---

[EDIT]

As lhf said in the commentaries, the number of additions can be further reduced.

We may define:

$c_i = b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_i$

The number of additions to compute all $c_i$ will be $n-1$, because we can obtain $c_{i+1}$ as $c_{i+1} = c_{i} + b_{i+1}$.

Then:

$s = a_1\,c_1 + a_2\,c_2 + a_3\,c_3 + ... + a_n\,c_n$

The number of additions in this form of $s$ is also $n-1$, so the total number of additions will be:

$\boxed{a = 2\,(n-1)}$

Comment: The number of additions can be reduced if you reuse say $b_1+b_2$ in $b_1+b_2+b_3$.